# Как обрезать список на jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Здравствуйте, есть массив списка

```
<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
</ul>
```

Как можно через jquery обрезать количество пунктов списка "li" до 3х?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var elements = $("ul li:lt(3)");
$('ul').html(elements);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

`lt` - отбирает все элементы с индексом меньше чем index среди уже отобранных элементов.

```
jQuery(':lt(index)')
```

`index` — Индекс элемента, начиная с нуля.

---

Еще вариант, отрезать через [slice](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8_%D0%B8%D0%B7_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8) и потом результат впихнуть обратно в `ul`

```js
var sliceCount = 3;
var els = $('ul li').slice(0, sliceCount);
$('ul').html(els);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

---

Самый простой вариант:

```js
$('ul li:gt(2)').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

[gt](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B_%D1%81_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5_n) - Фильтрует набор выбранных элементов, оставляя только те, индекс которых превышает n. Не забывайте, что индексирование начинается с 0.

Comment: `$('ul li:gt(2)').remove();` Так вы не трогаете существующие элементы, а лишь удаляете лишние. А значит не ломаете обработчики событий, данные, которые могут быть привязаны к остающимся элементам.

Comment: @AndryG Где-либо в вопросе написано про обработчики?

Comment: пример кода явно "академический". Я указал для будущих читателей, чем опасно пересоздание остающихся элементов.

Comment: @AndryG можете дополнить ответ, если хотите) Или даже добавить еще один